# How to transfer large sum from out of country to USA?

Tags: united-states, international-transfer, philippines

Is it easy or possible to do a large sum transfer from Philipines to USA by a Philippine citizen to buy her USA home?  What is best or safest practice?  I have concern about large sum restriction laws and taxes.  Funds from savings.  Hoping better solutions than sending $10K at a time?   Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: As others have said, there's no problem on the US end. You should find someone who can advise you on whether the Philipines will impose restrictions.

Comment: Did you ever find out if you could transfer money out of the Philippines to the US? The answers you have seem to be familiar with US laws but not Philippine law. I have heard PI will not allow transfers OUT of PI.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not familiar with the laws in the Philippines, but I know that there are no taxes or restrictions in the US on transferring money between accounts. Just wire-transfer it from your bank in Philippines to your bank in the US (or directly to the escrow, they'll provide instructions).

Why would you send $10K at a time? Are you laundering money? The 10K limit is when the banks are **required** to report transactions, but they can report even if the amounts are lower. For example, repetitive transactions just under the limit will likely to trigger the report, as it is suspicious. But what do you care about this report? If the money is yours and not originated from some illegal activity, you shouldn't worry about banks and governments pushing paper.

And just to put your mind at ease, when you buy the house, the escrow company bank will do the report anyway, because the payment for the house will probably be over $10K, and be done in cashier check or wire transfer (reportable transactions), so its not that you can avoid it anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you're trying to comply with some law in the Philippines don't go splitting it up into $10k chunks.  Such splitting is liable to draw the attention of US authorities.

There is no law against transferring in or out any amount in the US, the law pertains to reporting negotiable stuff (cash or other things that don't have your name on them) across the border.  Wire in $100k and there's no issue unless it's money the IRS should have known about but doesn't.

Comment: Its not "across the border". Any cash transaction above the limits will be reported.

Comment: @littleadv: It will be reported but you don't have to do anything about the reporting.  So long as there's no IRS issues the report is harmless.

Comment: yeah, I know, just pointing out that its not only for international transfers

Comment: (@littleadv) there's two _different_ things that could apply: banks and other businesses (automatically) report over 10k cash transactions to FinCEN (non-banks may now do so via IRS on Form 8300 or directly to FinCEN), and people importing 10k cash or negotiable instruments are required to declare it to Customs: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/71777/what-happens-if-one-brings-more-than-10-000-usd-with-them-into-the-us